require index.cjs not work in vite with puppeteer
I use electron to create a desktop app, and with vite to complie js file, I find vite seem not work with puppeteer, in the file vite generate, it always have error:
./build/index.cjs module not find
I check the file vite generate, it seem the problem is caused by the package yargs which import by the package of @puppeteer/browsers@2.3.0,
the follow code not be complied correct:
`const {Yargs, processArgv} = require('./build/index.cjs');
Argv(processArgv.hideBin(process.argv));
module.exports = Argv;`
The result in complied file is :
const{applyExtends:Yai,cjsPlatformShim:$ai,Parser:Zai,Yargs:Aoe,processArgv:esi}=require("./build/index.cjs");Aoe.applyExtends=(r,a,l)=>Yai(r,a,l,$ai);Aoe.hideBin=esi.hideBin;Aoe.Parser=Zai;module.exports=Aoe;
You can see the "./build/index.cjs" is still there, not be complied
I try to use vite common js plugin (@rollup/plugin-commonjs) and vite-plugin-require-transform plugin, also update the optimizeDeps in vite config file, but not work, my vite config file as follow:
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import alias from "@rollup/plugin-alias";
import * as path from 'path';
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills'
// import commonjs from 'vite-plugin-commonjs'
import ClosePlugin from './vite-plugin-close.ts'
// import { esbuildCommonjs } from '@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs'
import checker from 'vite-plugin-checker'
//import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import requireTransform from 'vite-plugin-require-transform';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy'
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
export default ({ mode }) => {
    process.env = { ...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd()) };

    return defineConfig({
        plugins: [alias(),
        nodePolyfills(),
        nodeResolve(),
        commonjs({
            include: 'node_modules/**',
        }),
        requireTransform({fileRegex:/.ts$|.tsx$|.js$|.cjs$/}),
        copy({
            targets: [
                { src: 'node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/node_modules/yargs/build/index.cjs', dest: '.vite/build/build' }   
            ]  
        }),
        ClosePlugin(),
        checker({
            // e.g. use TypeScript check
            typescript: true,
        }),
        ],
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
            },
        },
        optimizeDeps: {
            include: ['node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/node_modules/yargs/build/index.cjs'],
        },
        build: {
            sourcemap: true,
            commonjsOptions: {
                include: ["node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/node_modules/yargs/build/index.cjs"],
              },
            // rollupOptions: {
            //     plugins: [
            //         alias({
            //             entries: [
            //               { find: '@', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') }
            //             ]
            //           }),
            //         // nodeResolve({
            //         //     extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.cjs']
            //         //   }), 
            //     ]
            // },
            external: [
                'sqlite3'
            ]

        },
        test: {
            include: ['test/vitest/utilitycode/*.test.ts'],
        }
      
    })
}

I have to use copy plugin to copy the file, but there are still some error
